# jquery cycle plugin: pager not working

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-cycle

I'm using the jquery cycle plugin and backbone.js in my webapp. I'm initiating the pager in one of my Backbone views. Here's how I'm doing it right now...

```
var SlideView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#SlideViewTemplate').html()),
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        return $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
});

var SlideListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#SlideNavi'),

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'populate');
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        _(this.collection.models).each(function(item) {
            this.populate(item);
        }, this);

        $('#Slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            pager: '#SlideNavi'
        });
    },
    populateChildren: function(slide) {
        var itemView = new SlideView({
            model: slide
        });
        $(this.el).append(itemView.render());
    }
});
new SlideListView({collection: someCollection});
```

Here's my view template, nothing fancy:

```
<script type="text/template" id="SlideViewTemplate">
    <%= name %>
</script>
```

Here's how the view looks after being populated:

```
<div class="SlideNavi">
    <div>Service1</div>
    <div>Service2</div>
    <div>Service3</div>
    <div>Service4</div>
</div>
```

Now, `el` used in `SlideListView` is empty when the page is loaded. But after the view has been populated I call upon the jquery cycle plugin to start the slideshow. The thing is that slideshow is working, but the pager is not. No `activeClass` is being added to pager elements as shown [in this demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager.html)....

What am I missing over here?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3851568/206613). Make sure to include `jquery.cycle.all.js`, not `jquery.cycle.lite.js`.

Comment: hah, so basically your problem had nothing to do with the posted code, the pager just isn't available in the lite plugin :), good to know!